# Passing KML files to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I just became aware of KML files, did some reading and generated my first KML files off of google maps.  In my app I am linking to google maps, passing a publicly available file with the intent of opening the KML file on the users Google Maps or Chrome browser (not within my app).  Maps, or Google opens, but the kml file data/map isn't loading.  To confirm its public, the URL attempts to download the file from my website.

Doing a simple call like:

```
window.open("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https://myserver.com/files/maps/testMap.kml")
```

Maps successfully opens, but I get a "No Results Found" pop up. I do see my URL passed into the query section of the map - and the zoom is in the middle of the ocean off of Africa...and when I zoom to the map location (Tampa FL) nothing is there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @MrUpsidown - could you elaborate please?  I don't understand your response.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - I think I found what you mean.  By "sharing", I guess I need the link and not the KML file...or is there an alternative way to pass a downloaded KML file into google maps via URL link...or `window.open(...)`  ?

Comment: Share the contents of your KML file here. Are you sure your KML file is valid?

Comment: I am reading [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1173) that this is deprecated (see comments). You should use https://www.google.com/mymaps.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps no longer supports opening a KML file directly on the main page at maps.google.com.  You used to be able to enter the URL for a public KML file right in the Google Maps search bar and have it load directly, or load the KML via a URL parameter like you have in  your question (`?q=http...`), but that functionality was turned off some time ago.

Now, to load a KML file on a Google Map, you'll probably need to set up a web page with a Google Maps API instance on it, where you can use the API to load a KML file.  If it's a relatively simple KML, you could also try uploading it to a Google My Map, and using the share functionality in there to share a link or get an embed code.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  Another above had also informed passing a kml file as a url link was deprecated sometime ago.  I liked it though, because allows a file to be used versus a users account.  If a user deletes a shared map links will break, but a hard file ensured it would always work.